# Why can't I remove quotes using `strip('\"')`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can only remove the left quotes using `str.strip('\"')`:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fp :
    for line in fp.readlines() :
        print(line)
        line = line.strip('\"')
        print(line)
```

Part of results:

```
"Route d'Espagne"

Route d'Espagne"
```

Using `line.replace('\"', '')` gets the right result:

```
"Route d'Espagne"

Route d'Espagne
```

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your lines do not *end* with quotes. The newline separator is part of the line to and is not removed when reading from a file, so unless you include `\n` in the set of characters to be stripped the `"` is going to stay.

When diagnosing issues with strings, produce debug output with `print(repr(line))` or even `print(ascii(line))`, to make non-printable or non-ASCII codepoints visible:

```
>>> line = '"Route d\'Espagne"\n'
>>> print(line)
"Route d'Espagne"

>>> print(repr(line))
'"Route d\'Espagne"\n'
```

Add `\n` to the `str.strip()` argument:

```
line = line.strip('"\n')
```

Demo:

```
>>> line.strip('"')
'Route d\'Espagne"\n'
>>> line.strip('"\n')
"Route d'Espagne"
>>> print(line.strip('"\n'))
Route d'Espagne
```

Comment: Use `line = line.strip('\"\n')`?

Comment: @SparkandShine: exactly.